# cannot deselect module from list even when deleted from database

Tags: 7, database

Still trying to remove 3rd party module from drupal list of modules and have followed disabling modules manually tutorial here https://drupal.org/node/157632

It shows empty set from both modules I disabled and followed the cache instructions for mysql but the modules remain stuck in the list and ENABLED with no way of removing them.

Do I need to delete the module list somehow and have it rebuild itself or something?

Comment: Which module do you want to disable?

Comment: Sorry I've since managed to do it but I had to disable from database and then remove not once but twice from module folder then flush cache and then finally it was gone. nightmare